# Terminating resistor for SL2.1A controller?

Tags: resistors, usb, resistance, usb-device, usb-hub

I'm currently making PCB with an integrated USB hub that will use an SL2.1A chip and I'm wondering if I should use any kind of terminating resistors on data lines? I read the datasheet and couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

If application example in the IC datasheet does not show any external termination resistors, then you should not think about them. Proper termination in USB2 hubs is a standard feature.